# Data binding not working for FragmentA after returning from FragmentB

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, broadcastreceiver, android-viewbinding

My app has two fragments: `HomeFragment` and `StatusFragment`. `HomeFragment` binds some connection info to the UI. Info is obtained from **broadcast receiver**.  At the beginning, data binding works in `HomeFragment` but when user go to the `StatusFragment` and then back to the `HomeFragment`, info is not bind.

HomeFragment, StatusFragment and HomeFragmentViewModel classes are shown below:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private var connectionStatus: String? = "Offline"
    private var connectionType: String? = ""

    private lateinit var mReceiver: ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver
    lateinit var homeFragmentViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel
    lateinit var repo: Repository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding?.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        
        repo = Repository().getInstance()!!
        val viewModelFactory = HomeFragmentViewModelFactory(repo)
        homeFragmentViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java]

        binding?.homeFragmentViewModel = homeFragmentViewModel
        this.mReceiver = ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver()

        mReceiver.mData.observe(this, Observer {
            repo.setInfo(mReceiver.getData())
            homeFragmentViewModel.getConnectionInfo()
        })

        homeFragmentViewModel.navToStatusFragment.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it==true){
                this.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_statusFragment)
                homeFragmentViewModel.doneNavigateToStatusFragment()
            }
        })

        return binding?.root
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        requireActivity().registerReceiver(
            mReceiver, IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
        )
        repo.setInfo(mReceiver.getData())
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver)
    }

}
```

```
class StatusFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this){
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false)
    }

}
```

```
class HomeFragmentViewModel(private val repo: Repository?) : ViewModel() {

    private val viewModelJob = Job()

    private val _navToStatusFragment = MutableLiveData<Boolean?>()
    val navToStatusFragment: LiveData<Boolean?>
        get() = _navToStatusFragment

    private val _connected = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val connected: LiveData<String?>
        get() = _connected

    private val _connectionType = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val connectionType: LiveData<String?>
        get() = _connectionType

    init {
        _navToStatusFragment.value = false
    }

    var isConnected: LiveData<Boolean> = connected.map {
        when (it) {
            "Online" -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }

    fun doneNavigateToStatusFragment(){
        _navToStatusFragment.value = false
    }

    fun navigateToStatusFragment(){
        _navToStatusFragment.value = true
    }

    fun getConnectionInfo() {

        when (repo?.getInfo()?.value) {
            0 -> {
                _connected.value = "Offline"
                _connectionType.value = "Check Your Connection"
                _connectionDetails.value = null
            }
            1 -> {
                _connected.value = "Online"
                _connectionType.value = "Cellular"
                _connectionDetails.value = null
            }
            2 -> {
                _connected.value = "Online"
                _connectionType.value = "WIFI"
                _connectionDetails.value = null
            }
            3 -> {
                _connected.value = "Online"
                _connectionType.value = "VPN"
                _connectionDetails.value = null
            }
        }
        Log.d("LOGGED", "Info Checked ...")
    }


    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

I did:

- using `regiterReceiver()` in `onResume()`, too
- using `viewLifeCycleOwner` instead of `this` for `binding.lifeCycleOwner`
- using `popBackStack()` in `StatusFragment` when back button pressed

*UPDATE*: The problem is that after going back to HomeFragment, onCreateView() is invoked, but HomeFragmentViewModelFactory() is not invoked! -> I need it for sending new repo object to view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your update note: viewModel will not be recreated upon coming back to a fragment so the factory is not called.

You need to know about viewModel **Owner**. in order to create a viewModel we need a `ViewModelStoreOwner` which is an interface which we will see in a bit, and `activity`, `fragment`, `navgraph` and `navBackStackEntry` classes implement this interface. This is the **first** argument of `ViewModelProvider` which in your case is **this** which means the current fragment.

What does this `ViewModelStoreOwner` do? basically it has a map which it keeps the instances of the **viewModel** created, when asking for a **viewModel** using `ViewModelProvider` first it looks inside this map to see if it has created it or not, if it is created it returns the previously created **viewModel** otherwise it will call the `ViewModelFactory` to create a new one, after that it stores it in this map for later use.

What does that mean? for a fragment this map is create in **onCreate** callback and destroyed in **onDestroy** callback (not **onDestroyView**) so when you navigate to a new fragment, since this fragment is not yet destroyed, **The viewModel still exists in this map, therefore upon coming back the one from the map which is previously created is returned.**

**PossibleSolution**: Create a function in viewModel and pass the repo to it (instead of constructor arguments), or do not use viewModel at all!

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It worked for me, but is this way (using a function) correct according to the principles of the MVVM architecture?

Comment: sure why not, those rule say favor constructor injection when possible, but in your case it is not possible. and setting it from outside is a valid way of providing dependency. specially in your case when it is okay to sat it later (because how you use that variable)